# Duplicate routes / metatags from Friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Google just let me know that I have duplicate meta tags. This is coming because I have duplicate routes from setting friendly_id

```
/posts/2
/posts/awesome-post-about-ponys
```

How do I make the first one invisible to google/the DMZ?

Answer (score 1):

The method I'm using in a similar case is to manually catch non-nice url and make a redirect

```
if request.path != post_path(@post)
  redirect_to @post, status: :moved_permanently and return
end
```